# MVC how to add a TimePicker

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I would like to know how to integrate a time picker into an application. What I want to achieve is the ability to add a departure time and arrival time of a journey creation. I have managed to set the date in the model but am now stuck on how I build the time around this.

Model:

```
    [Key]
    public int JourneyId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
    public string DepartingFrom { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public int TrainId { get; set; }
    public virtual Train Train { get; set; }
    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I have just done is added an extra property to the model

```
 [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
```

and then used this in the view